# pointcloud_to_laser output value is constant

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using pointcloud_to_laser package in fuerte, the output laser range value is constant but when i use the same code in different laptop(electric) it works fine. Does anyone has a possible explanation for this behavior??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53592/pointcloud_to_laser-output-value-is-constant.../) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that I was using kinect.launch, launch file in turtlebot_bringup package. When I was calling this file I was not getting any pointcloud, but when I used openni.launch(openni_launch), kinect worked fine.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0